# Xcode UI test: How can I check something in the UI while a gesture is in progress?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode-ui-testing

My app supports a kind of dragging/panning gesture: The gesture begins after a short delay when the user presses the screen with one finger, and keeps pressing. The user can then drag/pan pan around the screen while keeping the finger on the screen. The gesture ends when the user lifts the finger.

While the user drags/pans around the screen the UI continuously updates. Among other things, a label is continously updated with a text that has certain information about the current gesture location. I would like to write a UI test that not only simulates the gesture, but also checks how the UI is updated while the gesture is in progress.

I have found the `XCUICoordinate` class which has the `pressForDuration:thenDragToCoordinate:` method. This looks as if it would allow me to simulate the gesture, but I can't see any way how I could, for instance, check that the label I mentioned contains a certain text **while the gesture is in progress**.

Is there an API that allows me to write the desired UI test?

My app is written in Objective-C, but a Swift answer is also acceptable.